# Reactstrap dropdown not working with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dropdown

**Goal**

Dynamically create dropdown menus via hooks.

---

**Challenge**

When I change a hook value to my dropdown, the dropdown does not open or close. Its stays closed.
When I hard code the dropdown in the return, the open and close functions correctly.

---

**Doesn't work** Using hooks

```
///Various required imports are here..


export default  function main(){
 const [testb, state_set_testb] = useState(<div></div>);

function toggle_dropdown_function(toggle_request) {
console.log("fffffffffffffffffffffff",toggle_request)
    state_set_dropdown_open(toggle_request)
  }  

 state_set_testb(<div onMouseEnter={() => toggle_dropdown_function(true)} onMouseLeave={() => toggle_dropdown_function(false)}>
  <Dropdown id="testa" isOpen={dropdownOpen} toggle={toggle_dropdown}>
    <DropdownToggle style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent", border: "none", paddingTop: '8px', paddingBottom: '8px', paddingleft: '10px', paddingRight: '10px', color: "grey", fontSize: "14px " }}
      color="light" >
      othera
      </DropdownToggle >
    <DropdownMenu  >
      <DropdownItem style={{ fontSize: "14px " }}>Some Action</DropdownItem>
    </DropdownMenu>
  </Dropdown>
  </div>)

return <div>{testb}</div>
}
```

---

**Works** Not using hooks

```
///Various required imports are here..


export default  function main(){

function toggle_dropdown_function(toggle_request) {
console.log("fffffffffffffffffffffff",toggle_request)
    state_set_dropdown_open(toggle_request)
  }  

return <div onMouseEnter={() => toggle_dropdown_function(true)} onMouseLeave={() => toggle_dropdown_function(false)}>
  <Dropdown id="testa" isOpen={dropdownOpen} toggle={toggle_dropdown}>
    <DropdownToggle style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent", border: "none", paddingTop: '8px', paddingBottom: '8px', paddingleft: '10px', paddingRight: '10px', color: "grey", fontSize: "14px " }}
      color="light" >
      othera
      </DropdownToggle >
    <DropdownMenu  >
      <DropdownItem style={{ fontSize: "14px " }}>Some Action</DropdownItem>
    </DropdownMenu>
  </Dropdown>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: Why do you place React elements in your state variable? This is not the idiomatic approach.

Comment: How would you accomplish my goal without using hooks? @Martin

To add to my goal, the main component will load much before the dropdown fetched data will be ready to render. The dropdown options and the number of dropdowns is fetched.

The only way I know how to change the state of the render I through hooks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you could accomplish it. Essentially you have a separate component called Dropdown and you push it to an array of dropdowns.

```
const { useState } = React;

const Dropdown = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState('Select');
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const items = ["orange", "pear", "apple"];
  return <div className={`dropdown`}>
    <div onClick={()=> setOpen(!isOpen)} className={"dropdown__header"} >{active}</div >
    {isOpen && 
    <div className={"dropdown__body"}>
      {items.map((item, index) => {
        return <div key={index} onClick={(e) =>  {
            setActive(item);
            setOpen(false);
          }}>{item}</div>
      })}
    </div>
     }
    </div>
} 


const Main = () => {
  const [dropdowns, setDropdowns] = useState([])
  const addDropdowns = () => {
    let updatedDropdowns = [...dropdowns];
    updatedDropdowns.push(<Dropdown />)
    setDropdowns(updatedDropdowns);
  }
  
  return (
    <div className={"main"}>
      <button onClick={addDropdowns}>
        Add Dropdown
      </button>
      {dropdowns.map((dropdown, index) => {
        return <div key={index}>{dropdown}</div>
       })}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Here is some [codepen](https://codepen.io/vtolenti89/pen/OJbzweY?editors=1111).

**UPDATE**

I managed to use reactstrap using the same approach and I did not notice any problems.
Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/vtolenti89/pen/QWGQdpY?editors=1111)

Comment: Thank you, However this partly works. When I use the Dropdown reactstrap component within your code above, It re-renders/fires constantly

Comment: @RandomStuff I did not experience this problem. I updated my answer with a new codepen using the reactstrap library